# Unimplemented constructor in abstract classes

Tags: c#

I saw a few `abstract` base classes `.NET` provides and I'm completely lost the way their constructors and virtual methods defined. For example, see `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` base class:

```
public abstract class ValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
    //     class.
    protected ValidationAttribute();
    ...
    protected virtual ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext);
}
```

But I can't do this in my own class:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass();      
}
```

> MyClass.MyClass() must declare a body because it's not marked abstract, extern, or partial

And I can't mark it `abstract` either:

> The modifier abstract is not valid for this item

I have no specific need `MyClass` to be like `ValidationAttribute` or other base classes in `.NET`. I just want to know how did they compile on the runtime.

Comment: What you see is the metadata, definitions of the class, not real implementation.

Comment: How you obtained source code for `ValidationAttribute`, did you use some decompiler? It looks like method bodies were removed, here https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs is more realistic version of it.

Comment: The code for `ValidationAttribute` is not valid either - if you look at the [_actual_ source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/R/bf57007a2f61c388.html) you'll see that all constructors have a body.  I suspect you're looking at metadata or a bad decompiler result instead of the actual source code.

Comment: @DStanley Yes F12 in visual studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not looking at the code of ValidationAttribute, you are looking at its metadata.

The [actual constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,39) looks like

```
protected ValidationAttribute()
    : this(() => DataAnnotationsResources.ValidationAttribute_ValidationError) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a body.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass(){}      
}
```

That is what they do.
https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs